# Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Tags: google-chrome, sendmessage

Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I want to send message to content_script.js from background.js but it show the message:
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

but the the contect_script.js can send message to background.js
could anybody help me to solve this. Thanks.